# Why is the sign of the last term in a Sturm sequence always constant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots

I have been given the definition of a Sturm sequence ($p_1,\dots, p_m$) as follows:

$$p_0 = a \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\\ p_1 = a'\\ \forall 1 < i < m: p_i(t) = 0 \implies \text{sig}(p_{i-1}(t))=-\text{sig}(p_{i+1}(t)) \\ \text{sig}(p_m)=const.$$

WLOG regarding a specific sequence fulfilling this conditions (Like Sturms purposed one or [Gleyse 1997](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0893-9659(97)00022-0)), what is the purpose of the last condition?

If you analyse given sequences, it is trivial to show that they fulfil the last condition, however I am not sure why this condition is nessesary to build a Sturm sequence.

Comment: There are infinitely many rational numbers already, so [tag:finite-fields] was an inappropriate tag.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @JyrkiLahtonen